# Can't write to stream inside event

Tags: c#, powershell, outputstream, streamwriter, httpserver

I am can try to run NHTTP(simple asynchronous HTTP server written in C# for the .NET framework. You can download this dll in [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHttp), or view source code on [github](https://github.com/pvginkel/NHttp)) But i am cant write my own response to client from my server, because **i am can't write to OutputStream.**

My powershell script:

```
Add-Type -Path "NHttp.dll"

$server = New-Object NHttp.HttpServer
$server.EndPoint =  new-object System.Net.IPEndPoint ([System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8080)


$RequestReceived = {

    $request = $EventArgs.Request
    $response = $EventArgs.Response

    $global:response = $response.OutputStream.CanWrite

    $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($response.OutputStream)
    $writer.AutoFlush = $true
    $writer.WriteLine("Hello World")    


}

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $server -EventName RequestReceived -SourceIdentifier RequestReceived -Action $RequestReceived

$server.Start()
```

Always when my server receive request from client $global:response=False

An error occurring in the Event, which occurs when the server receives a request:

```
writeErrorStream      : True
PSMessageDetails      : 
Exception             : System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exce
                        ption when calling the ".ctor" with "1" argument: "Stream wa
                        s not writable" ---> System.ArgumentException: Stream was no
                        t writable.
                          at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding en
                        coding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean leaveOpen)
                          at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(Stream stream)
                           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                          at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.AuxiliaryCon
                        structorInvoke(MethodInformation methodInformation, Object[]
                         arguments, Object[] originalArguments)
                          at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand.CallCons
                        tructor(Type type, ConstructorInfo[] constructors, Object[] 
                        args)
TargetObject          : 
CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationExceptio
                        n
FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comman
                        ds.NewObjectCommand
ErrorDetails          : 
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, C:\powershell_scripts\tmp\nhttp.ps1: line 18
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
```

And server response clean white page and StatusCode 200 to client.

But example for C# work perfectly:

```
using (var server = new HttpServer())
{
    server.RequestReceived += (s, e) =>
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(e.Response.OutputStream))
        {
            writer.Write("Hello world!");
        }
    };

    server.Start();

    Process.Start(String.Format("http://{0}/", server.EndPoint));

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Such behavior within the Action block when called Event created by Register-ObjectEvent occurs to me is not the first time. I try to solve it, changing "apartment" model(STA and MTA), but it not solve the problem. If you need i am have more examples.

Comment: You are not disposing of the StreamWriter in your powershell version, you need to wrap it in a try/finally block and dispose of it in the finally `finally
    {
        if ($null -ne $writer -and $writer -is [System.IDisposable])
        {
            $InputObject.Dispose()
        }
    }` It is not hard to wrap that up in to a [`Using-Object`](https://davewyatt.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/using-object-powershell-version-of-cs-using-statement/) commandlet

Comment: @ScottChamberlain deleted it in this example, that there is less code. This does not affect my problem. Write to the stream is not available until now. Please help with my problem.

Comment: Could you post a full stack, please? -> After you get the error run `$error[0] | fl * -force | out-string | clip` to put the error details in your clipboard.

Comment: @nohwnd i am update POST with full error text.